# Fully reset WiFi without rebooting computer?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

Having an issue where if my wifi disconnects, DHCP fails to work again until after rebooting my entire computer. Couldn't find any info as to why this happens in the first place, but was wondering if there was any way to achieve the same exact effect on the wifi without having to reboot the whole system. Tried turning it off and on, but this does nothing. Also tried `ifconfig en0 down` then `ifconfig en0 up`, but same result. Thanks.

Comment: While more information is highly welcome (e.g. which version of MacOS, which Mac, which router, connected to which band you are connected to, WPA3 or WPA2?) try: disable Private Relay (if available). Set the MTU to 1453 for your Wifi connection (Open _System Preferences>Network_ (open the padlock by entering the admin name and password ). Click on _Advanced >Hardware_ click on drop down arrows of configure and choose _Manually_. click on drop down arrows of MTU and select _Custom_ to change.)

Comment: My previous comments addresses instabilities and loss of the WLAN connection on a MacOS/iDevice - why do you think that only the DHCP service on your Mac is effected?